# issues with Unisharp laravel file manager TinyMCE integration

Tags: php, html, laravel

TinyMce works perfecly with unisharp laravel filemanager on my localhost but it has issues on server

In server I have created a folder beta and pasted entire laravel project inside it 
everything works smoothly but when we click on upload image button from tinymce it shows me below image

[image]

I have tried all the possible solutions still its not working on my server

on server the url is `domain-name/beta/public/index.php` and when uploading it

Any Help is Appreciated !!

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled? Or maybe you need to configure tinyMCE to use a specific URL. Like `domain-name/beta/public/laravel-filemanager` or something like that? Do you have some more error logs?

Comment: actually when i do domain-name/beta/public/index.php/laravel-filemanager  laravel filemanger window pops up but it doesn't display the images like the gallery after you uploaded images  and problem is that it appends the image URL to brower's url like domain-name/beta/public/index.php/photos/image1.jpg which is not the correct path but if i enter domain-name/beta/public/photos/image1.jpg then image loads so there is some problem in URL !!

Comment: Hm. Just a guess: a problem with url rewrite (check mod_rewrite if your webserver is Apache) and misconfiguration of tinymce or upload script :)

Answer (score 0):

In your config JavaScript file change from

```
path_absolute : "/",
```

to

```
path_absolute : "../../",
```