# Laravel Subfolder directory issues

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

My Laravel Project works fine on my local machine but not on my online server .

On my Online server i have created a directory called dev and pasted entire laravel project inside it , so now the url to access routes are domain-name/dev/profile

but fetching an uploaded image which reside inside my public/storage/upload/image is giving me an error that image could not be found !!

Any Kind of Help is Appreciated !!

Comment: What is the error? I think permission issue ?

Comment: when i try to display the uploaded images 
i get this http:domain-name/dev/public/storage/upload/image/5/imageName Not Found (404)

Comment: Check if the image exist on the specified path ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could be with the Symbolic link. Run command `php artisan storage:link` using CLI.

If you don't have CLI access with your c-panel, you can run the command programmatically. Add below code in your `routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::get('/sym-link', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

And visit `YOUR-DOMAIN/sym-link` once.

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-storage-directory

Comment: Thanks for the reply .... are you using any texteditor like tinymce or Ckeditor in any project of yours ?

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept the answer if that worked so it may help someone else too. Yes, I had used. I would suggest you create a separate question for that.

Comment: Actually i haven't used the answer you have suggested i came up with different approach and its working now

Comment: for tinyMce issue kindly check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367740/issues-with-unisharp-laravel-file-manager-tinymce-integration

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Share Hosting First Check Link Path using

```
 readlink -f storage
```

and if path is incorrect remove storage from public and create new symbolic link using :

```
ln -s ../storage/app/public storage
```

To Make sure link is created use `ls` and see if storage is in red color or not .if it is in red color then link created successfully. :)